# Append counter with another column of query if counter is greater than one

Tags: sql, mssql-jdbc

I am struggling to find simple solution for below query

```
select id, 
    (select count(1) from table2 where table2.Id = table1.Id and table2.IsActive = 1) as TotalCount,
groupid from table1
```

Now I want to add one more field FinalGroupId in this query.

FinalGropId = If Totalcount is greater than 1 and groupid is not null then append count with Groupid or else return groupid .

below is expected result.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Id  | TotalCount  | GroupId   |FinalGroupId
---------------------------------------------------------           
1   |     1       | 11111     | 11111
2   |     2       | 22222     | 22222-2
3   |     1       | 33333     | 33333    
4   |     3       | 44444     | 44444-3    
5   |     3       | null      | null
```

How to find **FinalGroupId** in **optimized** way?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question that will produce the result you have provided. Also add the data as editable text, not as an image

Comment: @NickW I've updated Question. basically FinalGroupId is expected result which I want to obtain, based on TotalCount and GroupId

Comment: Hi - you haven't added the source data that would produce the results that you have given

Comment: TotalCount and GroupId are the source data which will produce FinalGroupId

Comment: Source data means the actual set of row values in table1 and table2 that will produce the output you've given.

Answer (score 1):

Without access to some sample data its a bit of a gamble, but try this out.

```sql
SELECT 
  Id,
  TotalCount,
  GroupId,
  CASE 
    WHEN GroupId is not null AND TotalCount > 1 THEN GroupId || '-' TotalCount
    WHEN GroupId is not null AND TotalCount = 1 THEN GroupId
    ELSE null END as FinalGroupId
FROM
(    
  SELECT
    Id,
    GroupId,
    SUM( CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as TotalCount
  FROM
    table
  GROUP BY
    Id, GroupId
) g
```

Comment: thank you. I still need to add few more pieces into this query but this will help me till some extent :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . .

I might suggest `left join` and aggregation, such to simplify the expressions:

```
select t1.id, t1.groupid, count(t2.id) as cnt,
       concat(t1.groupid,
              case when count(t2.id) > 0 then concat('-', count(t2.id)) end
             ) as newcol
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.groupid;
```

`concat()` is convenient for this purpose for two reasons:

1. It ignores `NULL` values.
2. It automatically converts numbers to strings.